# Why cluster mode is much slower than client mode in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, graph, pyspark, cluster-computing

I have 15k graph object created using GraphFrame. Those graphs are pretty small(10-100 nodes, 10-100 edges for each graph). I just need to apply shortest path and certain other algorithms on each graph. My current implementation is I use a for loop to loop through all 15k graphs. Surprisingly, Cluster mode is much slow than client mode.

I processed 10 graphs. Below are the performance metrics for client mode and cluster mode. I am trying to find why cluster mode is slower than client mode. I just can't make sense of metrics.

**Configuration for cluster (Spark Standalone)** 
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Configuration for client mode:**

[image]

[image]

**Client mode:**

```
Scheduling mode = FIFO
Spark Context default degree of parallelism = 4
Aggregated Spark stage metrics:
numStages => 1019
sum(numTasks) => 3263
elapsedTime => 38675 (39 s)
sum(stageDuration) => 19177 (19 s)
sum(executorRunTime) => 41413 (41 s)
sum(executorCpuTime) => 6305 (6 s)
sum(executorDeserializeTime) => 6386 (6 s)
sum(executorDeserializeCpuTime) => 3382 (3 s)
sum(resultSerializationTime) => 82 (82 ms)
sum(jvmGCTime) => 1171 (1 s)
sum(shuffleFetchWaitTime) => 3 (3 ms)
sum(shuffleWriteTime) => 603 (0.6 s)
max(resultSize) => 23947 (23.0 KB)
sum(numUpdatedBlockStatuses) => 1848
sum(diskBytesSpilled) => 0 (0 Bytes)
sum(memoryBytesSpilled) => 0 (0 Bytes)
max(peakExecutionMemory) => 35651584
sum(recordsRead) => 16972
sum(bytesRead) => 22064469 (21.0 MB)
sum(recordsWritten) => 0
sum(bytesWritten) => 0 (0 Bytes)
sum(shuffleTotalBytesRead) => 1431309 (1397.0 KB)
sum(shuffleTotalBlocksFetched) => 4304
sum(shuffleLocalBlocksFetched) => 4304
sum(shuffleRemoteBlocksFetched) => 0
sum(shuffleBytesWritten) => 1205067 (1176.0 KB)
sum(shuffleRecordsWritten) => 8228
```

**Cluster mode**

```
Scheduling mode = FIFO
Spark Context default degree of parallelism = 16
Aggregated Spark stage metrics:
numStages => 1019
sum(numTasks) => 3371
elapsedTime => 119895 (2.0 min)
sum(stageDuration) => 114501 (1.9 min)
sum(executorRunTime) => 162486 (2.7 min)
sum(executorCpuTime) => 29376 (29 s)
sum(executorDeserializeTime) => 74342 (1.2 min)
sum(executorDeserializeCpuTime) => 11919 (12 s)
sum(resultSerializationTime) => 87 (87 ms)
sum(jvmGCTime) => 7422 (7 s)
sum(shuffleFetchWaitTime) => 20899 (21 s)
sum(shuffleWriteTime) => 1144 (1 s)
max(resultSize) => 61683 (60.0 KB)
sum(numUpdatedBlockStatuses) => 6097
sum(diskBytesSpilled) => 0 (0 Bytes)
sum(memoryBytesSpilled) => 0 (0 Bytes)
max(peakExecutionMemory) => 47185920
sum(recordsRead) => 16962
sum(bytesRead) => 22037962 (21.0 MB)
sum(recordsWritten) => 0
sum(bytesWritten) => 0 (0 Bytes)
sum(shuffleTotalBytesRead) => 1480503 (1445.0 KB)
sum(shuffleTotalBlocksFetched) => 4571
sum(shuffleLocalBlocksFetched) => 2361
sum(shuffleRemoteBlocksFetched) => 2210
sum(shuffleBytesWritten) => 1211392 (1183.0 KB)
sum(shuffleRecordsWritten) => 8228
```

Comment: What cluster container / driver settings did you use? Versus what client  settings?

Comment: Looks like you have slow executors ... `sum(executorRunTime)`

Comment: How can I systemically justify running on single processor is faster than on a cluster?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** You are using wrong tool for the job.

Very small graphs (*10-100 nodes, 10-100 edges for each graph*) don't benefit from distributed processing at all.

At the same time high cost abstractions used in distributed system like Spark add significant overhead, making it dominating cost.

In general:

- Distributed graph processing is hard.
- In most of the cases scaling up wins over scaling out.